# How to get command line arguments from VimL?

Tags: vim, argv, argc

How can I access the arguments that were given to Vim on the command line under Windows?

I'm looking for the the equivalent to `argv[]` in C.

Under linux you can read `/proc/self/cmdline`.
Example:

```
vim -c ":echo split( readfile( \"/proc/self/cmdline\", 1 )[0], \"\n\" )"

print

[
  'vim',
  '-c',
  ':echo split( readfile( "/proc/self/cmdline", 1 )[0], "\n" )'
]
```

`argc()` and `argv()` don't work. They just return number of files.
Example:

```
vim -c ':echo "argc:" . argc() . ", argv:" . string( argv() )' file1 file2

print

argc:2, argv:['file1', 'file2']
```

Comment: Oh, I see. The example makes the problem clearer. Unfortunately, there is no way to get these parameters via Vim. You'll have to use a OS-dependent solution, like you already did.

Answer (score 5):

```
:help argc()
:help argv()
:help argidx()
```

And maybe also `:help argument-list`, just to be sure.

*Simple example:*

```
for arg in argv()
  echo arg
endfor
```

Answer (score 2):

In the specific case of needing argv[0] (i.e., the name vim was called by), you can use `v:progname`.